# Rails destroy does not work and forwards to a wrong link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I am totally new to rails and struggle with the easiest stuff. I have the following problem:

When I try to destroy a search (from my model search) it does not work and I get redirected to "/search.48 (the search with id 48). It gives me the notice "We're sorry, but something went wrong." and in the console it says something with POST. Neither the search is deleted nor the redirect_to search_path is working. What am I doing wrong?

This is my controller:

```
def show
    @searches = current_user.searches
end

def destroy
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @search.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Search deleted"
    redirect_to search_path
end
```

This is my view show:

```
<% @searches.each do |search| %> 
<%= search.title %>
<%= search.description %>
<%= button_to "delete", search, method: :destroy %>
```

My routes.rb:

```
get 'search' => 'searches#show'
resources :searches
```

And I also included `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` in the ***application.html.erb*** as well as `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` in the ***application.js*** file.

So I really can't find my mistake.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! In my router I wrote get 'search' => 'searches#show' and somehow my controller was confused with the search_path. Since I renamed it to get 'mysearches' => 'searches#show' and mysearches_path it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In your view file, the code for the button should look like:

```
<%= button_to "delete", search, method: :delete %>
```

Note the method is `:delete`, not `:destroy`. It's a little confusing, because 'delete' is the REST verb, but 'destroy' is the controller action name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use your idea, the button appears and when I click it the page /search.48 is still loading and nothing is deleted...

Comment: I'm wondering whether the button is created incorrectly or the redirect is incorrect. I think if you are attempting to redirect to `search_path` after delete, it will generate the path using the search you just deleted, which might be why you're not seeing anything Try `redirect_to searches_path` in the controller (instead of `search_path`)

Comment: I think I got it! In my router I worte get 'search' => 'searches#show' and somehow my controller was confused with the search_path. Since I renamed it to get 'mysearches' => 'searches#show' and mysearches_path it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
  <%= button_to "Delete", { action: "delete", id: search.id },
                                    method: :delete %>
```

in you view.  Also it appears you are redirecting to search_path but I am guessing you want searches_path.